# What is the proper way of closing the port of a non-responding device file in VxWorks?

Tags: c++, c, select, ioctl, vxworks

I am currently working on an application in VxWorks that talks to a device file using the `read()` function and uses a set of `ioctl()`to configure the communication port. It happens sometimes that the `read()` is stuck forever because it waits for a message, but never gets the message. A following `ioctl(fd,FIOCANCEL,0)` will then never be reached.

My question is how I can use `select()` in combination with the FIOCANCEL to properly disconnect such that it is possible to do a `read()` again later.

I would also like to know the implementation of FIOCANCEL if that is possible, such I can modify it.

Answer (score 0):

`select()` on VxWorks is the same as select on any other POSIX platform (though I can't remember whether it modifies the timeout parameter like Linux does; POSIX say's either behaviour is fine).

Presumably you're talking about a serial port? Then that should be fine to include in a call to `select()`. You then won't need the ioctl(fd, FIOCANCEL, 0), because you'd only ever call `read()` if `select()` has indicated that there is indeed something to read. If `select()` times out, don't call `read()`.